# Uncaught SyntaxError : missing ) after argument list in my code

Tags: javascript

I have stange error, I don't understand why my images can't display.

```
    echo "<div id='img' style='height':200px;'width':200px></div>";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        var tab_nb_match_par_user = ".json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user).";    
                        //chart 1
                        var line1 = [];
                        for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user) {
                             line1.push([k, tab_nb_match_par_user[k]/2]);
                        }
                        var taille = 70;     
                        for (var k in tab_nb_match_par_user){
                            $('#img').append('<img src='stats_matching/' + k + '.gif' alt=' + k + ' title=' + k + ' width=' + taille + ' />');
                            taille = taille-6;
                        }</script>";
```

Comment: Your single quotes in the `.append()` function don't match, for example `'<img src='`, `'.gif' alt='`, it should look like this `.append('<img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt=' + k + ' title=' + k + ' width=' + taille + ' />')`. BTW you should also post the rendered JS, not just the PHP that generates it.

Comment: No cause I'm trying to escape the JS in the PHP, it's normal. I had also try in the JS and it work.

Answer (score 1):

You had quotes where you shouldn't have. You don't need quotes around css properties inside the style tag.

```
echo "<div id='img' style='height:200px;width:200px;'></div>";
```